# Running an action x times during t seconds uniformly

Tags: python, sockets, time

I want to repeat a task several times during an interval of time and I want to do that in an uniform way so if I want to do the task 4 times in 1 second it should be executed at t = 0, 0.25, 0.5 and 0.75.

So now I am doing:

```
import math
import socket

s = socket.socket(...) #not important 

time_step = 1./num_times_executed
for _ in num_times_executed:
    now = time.time()
    s.sendto(...) #action i do
    time.sleep(max(0,time_step-(time.time()-now)))
```

However there is a lot of overhead, the bigger the loop is the more drift I get. For example with num_times_executed = 800, it takes 1.1 seconds so ~ 10% wrong...

Is there a way to do that with a good precision ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
time_step = 1./num_times_executed
start = time.time()
for i in num_times_executed:
    s.sendto(...) #action i do
    next_send_time = start + (i+1) * time_step
    time.sleep(max(0,next_send_time - time.time()))
```

Now you're not going to get any drift because the time steps are firmly set values off of a start time. Previously the little calculations happening before setting now = time.time() would cause a tiny drift, but now so long as your time_step is long enough to execute the s.sendto(...) command, you shouldn't have any drift.